# How to read the first word in a text file and display it in a richTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a text document that has two alphanumeric words in it.  I would like to read the text file and display only the first one in my `richTextBox`

This is what I have so far but does not seem to work:

```
RichTextBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

try
{
    string filename = @"C:\Test\event.txt";
    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        var last = File.ReadLines(filename).Last();
        string[] words = last.Split(' ');
        Console.WriteLine(words[0]);
        richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("File does not exist.");
    }
}
catch (Exception f)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

At the moment it reads the entire text document.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean `display only the first one`?

Comment: So in my text file I have " testing123 document" .  I would like to display only the "testing123" in my richTextBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try to use `FirstOrDefault` get first line string, then use `Split` method to get the first word.

```
if (File.Exists(filename))
{
    var firstLine = File.ReadLines(filename).FirstOrDefault();
    richTextBox1.Text = firstLine.Split(' ')[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  It is working perfectly now.  Saw where I went wrong.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @Dev2468 No problem glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are consoling out the answer, just set:

```
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename).split(' ')[0];
```

There are probably more esoteric and performant ways to do this through binary or char reading; but this should solve your issue.